# How do I upgrade gradle in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using a Mac OS X version 10.11.5 (15F34).
I am using Android Studio 2.1.2 (built on May 26, 2016).
I downloaded grade-2.13-all.zip and unzip to /usr/local/grade-2.13 and set in an environment variable.  It works when I run 'gradle -v' from any location in my terminal

In the 'gradle-wrapper.properties' file I replaced
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1.2-all.zip

with

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip

Using Android Studio I clicked on File > Project Structure > Project.  On screen I set the Gradle version to 2.13 and the Android Plugin Version to 2.13 (I don't think is right but not sure which should be).

I have latest Android SDK as of last early June 2016.

In Android Studio I clicked on Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle    On screen I selected the radio button 'Use local gradle distribution'  Gradle home:  /usr/local/gradle-2.13

However, gradle build or gradle sync fail

I get

Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.13.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.13/gradle-2.13.pom
    file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.13/gradle-2.13.jar
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.13/gradle-2.13.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.13/gradle-2.13.jar
Required by:
    :android:unspecified

Answer (score 0):

I just tried something and it seems like the problem is fix now:
I set the Android Plugin version back 2.1.2 but left the Gradle version to 2.13

Gradle Build and Sync was successful with no errors.